# "Sometimes" vs. "Occasionally"

Tags: word-usage, word-choice, difference

I am building a survey. I found one that uses this scale for asking about frequency of doing something:

> 1.Very often
>
> 2.Sometimes
>
> 3.Occasionally
>
> 4.Rarely
>
> 5.Never

I want to change it to:

> 1.Always
>
> 2.Sometimes
>
> 3.Rarely
>
> 4.Never

Does the second list of choices do the same purpose of the first list?

I think that ***sometimes*** and ***occasionally*** are almost the same (especially in my language as I am a non-native speaker and need to translate this survey to my language). Am I right that ***sometimes*** and ***occasionally*** are the same in English language and these two choices can be merged with **sometimes**?

The other thing, is ***very often*** equivalent to ***always***? Again, because I will need to translate these answers to my language. I find ***very often*** is same as ***always*** (at least in my language). So can I replace **very often** with **always**?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Very often is not the same as always. Always is every time, while very often is most of the time, in the best way I can rephrase it. Sometimes and occasionally however mean about the same thing, it should be fine to remove one.